# Javascript: Integer exceeding 10^308 (maximum value)

Tags: javascript, numbers, calculator, largenumber, rubiks-cube

I'm trying to make a program that you can enter the dimensions of a Rubik's cube eg. 13x13x13 and the program tells you how many permutations there are for that Rubik's cube. I have the math to figure it out, but in case you didn't know Rubik's cubes can have a lot of permutations. Just a 13x13x13 has 13.421 novemoctagintillion (1.34 * 10^271). I can't calculate anything past a 14x14x14 rubik's cube because the number of permutations exceeds 10^308

How can I some store a number larger that 10^308 in Javascript?

Here is my code so far,

```
function calc(){
    Calc.d = Number(document.getElementById("dimensions").value);
    Calc.c = factorial(8) * Math.pow(3,8) / 3;
    Calc.eNumber = (Calc.d - 2) * 12;
    Calc.e = factorial(Calc.eNumber) * Math.pow(2,Calc.eNumber) / 2;
    Calc.a = Calc.c * Calc.e / 2;
    document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = String(convert(Calc.a));
}
```

Can anyone help?
Thank you!!!

Comment: Is this really a duplicate ? Linked question was asking for a BigNum library not for a way to store those.